# heroku collaborate without cloning

Tags: heroku, clone, collaboration

I have been invited to join a heroku collaboration. I received the email:

> Since you already have an account with Heroku, you can get started by
>   simply git cloning the app repository:
>
> git clone git@heroku.com:.....

The other collaborators and myself are already pushing/pulling to the same github repo, so I already have a copy of the code.

From the Heroku dev center (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collab):

> $ heroku git:clone -a APPNAME This will create a directory called
>   APPNAME, with a full copy of the git repository. It also sets up a git
>   remote called heroku.

So, what do I have to do to just setup the git remote to heroku? I know that I could just dump my copy and clone over it, but I don't want to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run `heroku git:remote -a APPNAME` from inside your existing git directory.

You can also do this directly with `git remote` -- see your application in the heroku control panel to find the git address.

I do not recommend using `heroku git:clone` as the documentation details since, as it sounds like you do, you should be using a separate git hosting provider such as github to actually manage your source code.

Comment: Is there a way to set the name of the added remote? By default it's `heroku`.

Comment: Ah, found it: `heroku git:remote -a [app name] -r [remote] 
`